# How do you merge certain items in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6

Say you have the following array:

```
const ab = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'];
```

How would you change this array so that all the "b" items get grouped together, until you hit another "a".

So the result of the above array would look like:

```
['a', 'a', 'bbb', 'a', 'bb', 'a'];
```

I'm trying to solve a problem with wrapping span tags around words that match a patter in a React app, but this is *essentially* my problem.

I've been working at it for ages but can't come up with anything I'm happy with.

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: What's the pattern?

Comment: Why aren't the first two `a` merged?

Comment: @adiga He said he wants to group b's

Comment: I mis-typed the desired output initially, please see edited response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count repeating occurences, then build the result based on that:

```
 const result = [];
 let curr = array[0], count = 1;

 for(const el of array.slice(1).concat(undefined)) {
   if(el !== curr || el !== "b") {
     result.push(curr.repeat(count));
     curr = el, count = 1;
   } else count++;
 }
```

Comment: Why the substring? You will group 'boo' in with other 'b's?

Comment: @paulpro otherwise `bb` wouldn't get grouped with `b` again ... but you are right, haven't thought of `boo`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the elements will always be single letters, you can merge the elements, then match on either `b`s or non-`b`s:

```
ab.join('').match(/(b+|.)/g)
```

```js
const ab = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'];

let output = ab.join('').match(/(b+|.)/g);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) you could do something like this.

I'm assuming the first two characters in your solution were a typo.

```js
const data = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'];

const res = data
.reduce((a,c)=>{
  const lastIndex = a.length - 1;
  if(a[lastIndex] && a[lastIndex].includes('b') && c === 'b') a[lastIndex] += c;
  else a.push(c);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to merge `b` then you could use `reduce` like this:

If the current item and the previous item are `b`, then append it to the last accumulator item. Else, push it to the accumulator

```js
const ab = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']

const output = ab.reduce((acc, c, i, arr) => {
  arr[i-1] === "b" && c === "b" 
    ? acc[acc.length - 1] += c
    : acc.push(c)
    
  return acc;
},[])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to give an explanation for this but using reduce you can do it like this:

```js
const ab = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'];

function merge(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc,cur, index) => {
    if(arr[index - 1] === 'b' && cur !== 'a') {
      acc[acc.length - 1] = acc[acc.length - 1] + cur;
      return acc;
    }
    acc.push(cur);
    return acc;
  },[]);
}

console.log(merge(ab))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you're after:

```js
var ab = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'];

var index = 0;
var groupedArray = [];
var firstOccurence = true;
var groupedString = "";
var grouping = false;
for (var a = 0; a < ab.length; a++) {

  if (ab[a] == "a") {
    if (grouping) {
      grouping = false;
      firstOccurence = true;
      groupedArray.push(groupedString);
    }
    groupedArray.push(ab[a]);
  } else {
    if (firstOccurence) {
      groupedString = "";
      firstOccurence = false;
    }
    groupedString += ab[a];
    grouping = true;
  }
}
console.log(groupedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can `stringify` your array then split it with a match of `b` or more or any other character

```js
const ab = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'];

const res = ab.join("").match(/(b{1,}|.)/g);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just map through the `ab` array and if the current element is `a`, push it to a new array but if the current element is `b`, check if the previous element is `b` or not, and if it is, merge the current element to the previous element else just push the `b` to the new array.

```js
const ab = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'];

let arr = [];

ab.map((e,i) => {
  if(i > 0) { // check if element is the first one or not
    if(e == "b") { 
      if(ab[i - 1].indexOf('b') > -1) { // check if prev element is "b" or not
       arr[arr.length-1] += e; // merge if prev element is "b"
      } else {
       arr.push(e);
      }
    } else {
      arr.push(e);
    }
  } else {
   arr.push(e);
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

---

**N.B.** The `reduce()` method approach and the `regex` approach shown in the other answers are cleaner and more concise as compared to the `map()` method approach shown above though.